# capturing the REAL output of python function ran from subprocess.Popen module

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run my file "counting.py" in terminal but not directly. I am using subprocess module from "almost.py" which tells the terminal to run a specific function "count(a, b)" in counting.py.

***count(a, b) takes two strings a and b and return the total word count

almost.py is successfully guiding the terminal to run count(a, b) in counting.py. However, I am unable to retrieve the real output of the count(a, b) function after it is run through subprocess. How can I do so?

almost.py

```
import subprocess 
output = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'counting.py', 'count', '"let roll"', '"love it most "'])
print (output) #it is not actually return the real value of count(a, b)!!!
```

counting.py

```
from sys import argv

def count (a, b): 
    word = False 
    a = " " + a + " "
    b = " " + b + " "

    result = 0 

    for i in range (len (a)-1): 
        if a[i] == " " and a[i+1] != " ":
            word = True 
            result += 1
        else: 
            word = False

    for i in range (len (b)-1): 
        if b[i] == " " and b[i+1] != " ":
            word = True 
            result += 1
        else: 
            word = False


    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(count (argv[2], argv[3]))
```

Comment: Why'd you even do that if you can `import counting` and then call `counting.count` right from Python without any subprocesses?

Comment: @ForceBru because I am trying to learn the concept. The original project involves running a bash file from terminal not counting.py which is why I have to use subprocess to run the file and not import it

Answer (score 0):

subprocess module will return subprocess.Popen python object.

you can do same think with this code.

```
from counting import count

output = count("let roll","love it most")
print output
```

Comment: The original project involves running a bash file from terminal not counting.py which is why I have to use subprocess to run the file and not import it. therefore, i am looking for retrieving output using subprocess